# Open windows in specific coordinates using Matlab?

Tags: macos, matlab, window, organization

My code opens 4 text file using :

```
system('open 1.txt'); %using MAC OS
system('open 2.txt');
system('open 3.txt');
system('open 4.txt');
```

and shows them as stacked order :

[image]

But I would like to show them like this :

[image]

Is this possible using matlab ?

Answer (score 0):

Not using pure Matlab, no. Really you need to look into how to programatically reposition windows in osx, then write a program/mexFunction wrapping that part up for Matlab to call.

On a windows system I would probably look for the relevant Windows API calls, for Mac I am not sure. Hopefully someone else on SO knows.